# Trying to use two props in custom defined component in react native, but it doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, react-native, components, react-props

I am adding two props (textProp & imgProp) to my custom component, but I keep on getting this error `<Image> component cant contain children`. This is what I have soo far

```
function TextImg(textprop, imgprop) {
  return(
    <div>
      <div>
        <Text>{textprop.text}</Text>
      </div>
      <div>
        <Image source={imgprop.imageUri}>!</Image>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Can anyone help me regarding this, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Images (img) are considered empty elements and are self-closing, and *required* to be per the html spec.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Empty_element

The react native [Image](https://reactnative.dev/docs/image.html) has the same restriction.

They can't wrap anything or have any children nodes. The "!" is the issue.

```
<Image source={imgprop.imageUri}>!</Image>
```

Try instead

```
<Image source={imgprop.imageUri} />
```

If you need to display an "!" then it'll have to be outside the image.

Comment: Oh, my bad I didn't want '!' there, it was a typo. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

if you need to show "!" in image,

Try

```js
<View>
  <Image source={img} />
  <Text
    style={{
      position: "absolute",
      // some stylng
    }}
  >
    !
  </Text>
</View>
```